# want to play an audio only once when user tap on option menu item

Tags: android

i want to play an audio  only once when clicked on option menu item. When user next time tap on the same item  the audio will be stop i think on that but can't find any solution help me to resolve my problem. here is my code. when user alternately tap on the item the audio will play and stop alternately.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater menuInflater= getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId()== R.id.item1)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AthravaShirshaActivity.this, EnglishExpln.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(item.getItemId()== R.id.item2)
    {
        MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(AthravaShirshaActivity.this, R.raw.mantra);
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
        item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make `mp` public and init it in your onCreate()  `MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(AthravaShirshaActivity.this, R.raw.mantra);`

now in `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
         {
             mp.stop();
         mp=null;
             item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
         }
         else
         {
                    mp= MediaPlayer.create(AthravaShirshaActivity.this, R.raw.mantra);
            mp.start();
                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                    {
                        mp.stop();
                    }
                });
                item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
         }
```

Comment: i tried the modifications u suggested but it is working only once means audio will play and stop only once next time tap nothing happen.